# Getting array elements to end at a particular keyword and shifting the rest to the next line in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, split

I am reading a text file into an array in perl and looping through the array to do stuff on it. Whenever there is a "begin", "end" or a ";" anywhere in the text, I want my array element to end there and whatever comes after any of those keywords to be in the next element to make life easier for me when I try to make sense of the elements later.

To achieve this I thought of reading the entire file into an array, replacing all "begin" with "begin\n", "end" with "end\n" and ";" with ";\n", writing this array back to a file and then reading that file back to an array. Will this work ?

Is there a more elegant way to do this rather than use messy extra writes and reads  to file?

Is there a way to short (in the electrical circuits sense if you know what I mean!) a read file handle and a write file handle so that I can escape the whole writing to the text file but still get my job done?

Gururaj

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split` with parentheses to keep the separator in the result:

```
open my $FH, '<', 'file.txt' or die $!;
my @array = map { split /(begin|end|;)/ } <$FH>;
```

Comment: Thanks! Although it didnt work for <$FH> , I did `my @array = <$FH>; my @array1 = map { split /(begin|end|;)/ } @array; ` and it worked

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use a Perl one-liner and avoid manipulating arrays altogether:

```
$ perl -pi -e 's#(?<=begin)#\n#g; s#(?<=end)#\n#g; s#(?<=;)#\n#g;' file.txt
```

Comment: Is the inverted comma correct? there seems to be only one opening one and no closing one. Also I have seen s/../../ being used , does the # have the same meaning or anything special? and what is the ?<= supposed to do? Could you explain that too please?

Comment: @gururaj : Fixed the missing apostrophe. While `s///` is common, the delimiter can be almost anything, so `s###`, `s!!!`, `s___` are all equivalent. This feature helps avoid situations where the delimiter is part of the regex itself. `?<=` is a look-behind assertion. See [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) for more info.